# WickedPDF generated PDF file upload with shrine does not populate data field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2, shrine

I am migrating from Paperclip my whole uplading process and have a problem regarding generated PDF.

Child model that handles the upload is a polymorphic model named `quotepdf`

At some point a `quotepdf` instance is generated and has an attachment linked to it.

Here is the quotepdf model adapted for shrine

```
class Quotepdf < ApplicationRecord
  include QuotesAndInvoicesUploader::Attachment.new(:quote)    
  belongs_to :quotable, polymorphic: true

end
```

the uploader :

```
class QuotesAndInvoicesUploader < Shrine
    plugin :validation_helpers # to validate pdf
    plugin :delete_raw

    Attacher.validate do
        validate_max_size 1.megabyte
        validate_mime_type_inclusion ['application/pdf']
    end

    def generate_location(io, context)
        type  = context[:record].class.name.downcase if context[:record]
           name  = super

        [type, name].compact.join("/")
      end

end
```

and the Sidekiq worker that handles the creation of the 'quotepdf record' and PDF attachment with Wickedpdf :

```
class PhotographerQuotePdfWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options retry: false

  def perform(id)
    @quote = Photographerquote.find(id)
    ac = ActionController::Base.new()
    pdf_string = ac.render_to_string pdf: 'photographerquote-'+@quote.hashed_id.to_s, template: "photographerquote/print_quote.pdf.erb", encoding: "UTF-8", locals: {pdfquote: @quote}

    new_pdf = @quote.build_quotepdf
    new_pdf.quote = StringIO.new(pdf_string)
    new_pdf.save
  end

end
```

With Paperclip it used to work fine. Though with shrine, nothing is saved into the 'quote_data` column of the new 'quotepdf' record.
The worker is returning no error also.

Cached file is indeed uploaded to S3 bucket so PDF file is generated properly. Final file is missing.

**EDIT**

got it working by stripping my uploader to bare :

```
class QuotesAndInvoicesUploader < Shrine

    def generate_location(io, context)
        type  = context[:record].class.name.downcase if context[:record]
        name  = super 

        [type, name].compact.join("/")
    end

end
```

But I don't understand why it failed previously: file is only 22KB and is indeed PDF. Cannot be a validation problem..

**EDIT 2**

Ok mimetype detected is indeed `null`

```
{"id":"devispdf/04aa04646f73a3710511f851200a2895","storage":"store","metadata":{"filename":null,"size":21613,"mime_type":null}}
```

Although my intialiser has `Shrine.plugin :determine_mime_type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your background job, try seeing what this outputs:

```
Shrine.determine_mime_type(StringIO.new(pdf_string))
```

If it's `nil`, then I would recommend trying a different analyzer (e.g. `:mimemagic` or `:marcel`).

```
Shrine.plugin :determine_mime_type, analyzer: :mimemagic
# or
Shrine.plugin :determine_mime_type, analyzer: :marcel
```

If that fails, you can also use an extension-based analyzer such as `:mime_types` or `:mini_mime`, and in your background job assign a temporary file with an extension:

```
tempfile = Tempfile.new(["quote", ".pdf"], binmode: true)
tempfile.write pdf_string
tempfile.open # flush & rewind

new_pdf = @quote.build_quotepdf
new_pdf.quote = tempfile
new_pdf.save! # fail loudly if save fails
```

Alternatively, since you're attaching in a background job, you can simply avoid temporary storage and validations altogether:

```
pdf_file = StringIO.new(pdf_string)
uploaded_file = new_pdf.quote_attacher.store!(pdf_file)
new_pdf.quote_data = uploaded_file.to_json
new_pdf.save!
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Janko. Actually `Shrine.determine_mime_type(StringIO.new(pdf_string))` actually return `application/pdf`. So not very sure why validation failed. But your correct the validation is not really necessary anyway. And I have used your solution to bypass the cache file. The metadata populated does show the correct mime type (escaped). The file name still has to be populated manually. But it's all good.